# How does pypy2 compare to pypy3 in speed benchmarks?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, python-2.7, pypy

It's well-known pypy3 is faster than CPython for number-crunching tasks not already written in C: https://speed.pypy.org/

But how does pypy2 compare to pypy3 in terms of speed? Pypy used to only support only Python 2, but both pypy2 and pypy3 are [built on the same codebase](https://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/release-v7.3.9.html), so they should expect to run about the same speed. I recall in earlier versions of python 3, number-crunching and string operations in pure python (NOT numpy) ran slower due to integer sizes and unicode strings, but I'm not sure if this is the case now. If the speed is comparable, I can drop the compatibility imports for the code designed for pypy2.

In the comparison at https://speed.pypy.org/comparison/ I compared cpython 2.7.11, cpython 3.7.6, pypy-jit-64 latest (I think this is compatible with python 2.7.11), pypy3.9-jit-64 latest. pypy vs pypy3 seem comparable in speed on tasks ai, float, go, json_bench, scimark_fft but I'm not sure if I did the comparisons correctly and didn't find which codebases the benchmarks come from.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better to ask "how does PyPy perform on my tasks" rather than search for a generic "what is faster" measure. Those generic measures are only one way to composite the scores. What matters at the end of the day is how to best implement the task that interests you.

Comment: so profile previous code i've written? my use case is project euler problems I'm too lazy to write in C++ (which is what they really should be written in)

Comment: also does "pypy-jit-64" refer to python 2.7 compatible python

Comment: On speed.pypy.org "pypy-jit-64" refers to python 2.7 compatible python